# Activating a circuit based on change of resistance

Tags: sensor, time

I am looking to use a sensor, such as photoresistor, to activate a circuit only when there is a significant change in the input. Such as when the light incident on the photoresistor changes significantly (e.g. something suddenly blocks or unblocks the light source).

What would I need to make this circuit? Ideally when the resistance changes by a certain amount quickly it would activate a transistor or switch.

I'm not sure where to start with this one without using a computer to process the time taken and calculate a  derivative.

**edit:**
It must be a microcontroller free solution. I'm not fussy about the tolerance or what-ifs from environmental variables, so long as the circuit can detect large resistance changes.

Comment: A differentiator can be made with an op-amp, a resistor and a capacitor. There's a lot more to it than that. Look at PIR motion detector circuits.

Comment: motion sensors work best with a pulsed burst signal echo detect. Then integrated with threshold detection. With IR you can easily detect motion in a 60 degree span to 10m or more

Comment: You need to specify your operational requirements. Do you want the detection only when the LDR goes from light to dark ...or do you want to include whenever there is a major change in illumination (either brighter or dimmer). Does a slow change need to be ignored? For example if the LDR was outdoors would you want it to be triggered as you pass through a day to night transition? Without specs it's hard to help.

Comment: @JackCreasey I want it to activate when it goes from light to dark, or dark to light. Bi-directional. And only for _significant_ changes. So yes, slow changes should be ignored.

Comment: Define slow changes.

Comment: @JackCreasey A change in the amount of light that happens at a low speed. The kind of changes that I'm interested in will be happening in under a second or two, usually in significantly less than a second. The change in light will be present for many minutes.

Comment: Can you use a microcontroller?  Or, are you looking for a microcontroller-free solution?  What's the "price" [or tolerance] for false-positives and false-negatives?

Comment: This problem is under-constrained and I'm voting to close it. Here's why: If the circuit triggers on a fast change in light and then the light slowly dims, the output remains triggered and if then another fast change in light comes along nothing will happen because it's already triggered. You need to think about the what-ifs.

Comment: @Andyaka that is the intended behaviour of the circuit I would like.

Comment: @NickAlexeev It must be a microcontroller free solution. I'm not fussy about the tolerance or what-ifs from environmental variables, so long as the circuit can detect large resistance changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a computer to calculate a derivative, a small micro-controller will do that just fine. In the simplest case, taking the difference between a value now and a value X seconds ago is enough.

If you expect that any kind of tuning will be required (adjusting the threshold, filtering noise etc.), changing the MCU firmware will be easier than re-soldering RC filters.

Plus, if you use the MCU you get any reasonable processing logic for free. Activate when A *and* B are true? Keep activated for XX seconds? No problem.

If you insist on using analog components, you should take a look at a diff amplifier:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Usually comparator circuits are used with sensors like photoresistors, the photoresistor is put in series with another resistor to form a resistor divider. The comparator detects whether the voltage reaches a given level set by the potentiometer.

This allows for a circuit that can detect light levels based on a threshold.

[image]
Source: http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/LM741-night-light-circuit.php